# My picture is created in page 2 but paragrah created after is inserted before (page 1)

Tags: image, itext

I'm using itextsharp (itext) and I'm setting pictures like that:

```
img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/ActionPlan/uploads/") + doc.path);
float width = (document.PageSize.Width / 100 * 88) / 2;  // half width of the page
float height = width / img.Width * img.Height;
img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(width);
img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(height);
document.Add(img);
```

And text like that:

```
document.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
document.Add(new Paragraph("Document : " + doc.path, times));
```

This is the application's sequece for my app:

1. Paragraph that takes 80% of the page height
2. Picture (sometimes it fits on page 1 sometimes page 2)
3. One line of text

This is the PDF result if picture is higher than the rest of the page:

1. Parapgraph
2. one line of text
3. picture

I want the picture's name after the picture in any case. How did I fix this?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `writer.StrictImageSequence = true` to make sure that the text and images are printed in the same same sequence that are added.

More information at https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-arent-images-added-sequentially.

Comment: Definitively a better solution than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I check the image height and the remain space. if there is no remain space, I create a page break.

```
img = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Audit/uploads/") + item.link);
float width = (document.PageSize.Width / 100 * 88) / 2;  // resize picture to half width of the page
float height = width / img.Width * img.Height;
img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(width);
img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(height);

if ((pdfWriter.GetVerticalPosition(false) - document.BottomMargin) < height)
    {
        document.NewPage();
    }
document.Add(img);
```